# Bootstrap complex layout

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap, complexity-theory

How much row do you recommend to use in this layout?. I think I'm doing something wrong because I can not get the location of the `SPAN 4 SPAN 4 INTO ROW`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi87u.jpg

Comment: Would be best to include the image in your post and not as a link. Also, your question is hard to understand.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem doing what you want, you just need to be carful with the HTML when you have nested columns. Here's a working example with fluid rows http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/yYFMT/

When using fluid rows, note that spans of the nested columns add to 12 and the HTML is

```
<div class="row-fluid">

<div class="span8">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">nested col</div>
  <div class="span6">nested col</div>
 </div> <!-- end nested row -->

</div> <!-- end span 8 parent  -->

<div class="span4">
span 4
</div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

If you don't have fluid rows, the spans of the nested columns add up to the width of the parent, eg

```
<div class="row">

<div class="span8">

<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">nested col</div>
  <div class="span4">nested col</div>
 </div> <!-- end nested row -->

</div> <!-- end span 8 parent  -->

<div class="span4">
span 4
</div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

Here's a working example of with non-fluid rows: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/MX6GK/

Good luck!